# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando un proyecto en react, con la plantilla AdminLTE, ya hice funcionar mi login y todo lo demás, el detalle es que a partir de que cree un componente para crear usuarios, cada que guardo me quita los estilos css, y me salen los siguientes errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo curioso es que al bajar y volver a encender el servidor, funciona y no detecta ningún error, pero hago un cambio y vuelve a salir lo mismo aquí un foto donde funciona perfecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Control Gastos, Conasim."
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

    <title>Control gastos</title>
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="wrapper"></div>
    </div>

  </body>

  <!-- jQuery 3 -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Esta es la estructura de mis carpetas, copie los archivos de la plantilla tal y como estaban en el paquete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi consola marca igualmente que todo esta correcto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "<URL>".
create:16 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/user/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css".
create:18 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/user/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css".
create:20 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/user/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css".
create:22 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/user/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css".
create:24 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/user/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css".
```

Comment: Si todo está perfecto entonces donde está el error?

Comment: El problema esta en que al hacer un cambio y aplicarlo desaparecen los estilos css, tal como la primera imagen y salen esos errores por consola

Comment: Pero esos errores son más bien de jQuery bootstrap y adminLTE, no?

Comment: En teoría si, pero el detalle es que al iniciar con npm start no marca ningún solo error, pero cuando hago cualquier cambio así se añadir un div sin clase aparecen esos errores y ya no tiene estilos pero si reinicio el servidor vuelve a funcionar

Comment: No, en teoría no, ahí en lo poco que podemos ver en tu screenshot (por cierto, no son la mejor manera de mostrar donde requiere ayuda), se ve claro. Te recomendaría usar Sentry.io para facilitarte depurar ese error como una excepción. Tal vez tenga que ver con caché o como están interactuando los scripts de tu plantilla con el código que genera webpack, podemos especular mil cosas, pero necesitas más que screenshots para descubrir el error y se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Okey muchas gracias, ya acabo de implementar sentry.io, adjunte los errores en la pregunta

Comment: Esos errores podrían ser porque la plantilla de AdminLTE no es tan compatible como puedes ver, con el servidor de webpack, te recomendaría googlear ese mensaje del "interpreted as ... But transferred with..." con respecto a `webpack-dev-server` o `create-react-app`, podría ser ya algo tan común que tu mismo podrías compartir la solución acá y ganarte más puntos por compartir la solución a tu pregunta. O darnos más elementos para ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! encontre la solucion.

Comment: Excelente! Compártela aquí mismo como answer!

Comment: Listo ya la compartí, mil gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando un poco el error arrojado por sentry.io, encontre esta pregunta:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)
ahi viene la explicacíon y el porque del error ademas de varias opciones de como solucionarlo, para mi funciono, simplemente agregar un slash antes de la ruta del css, algo como esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Wow es tan simple que casi es increíble! No te olvides de marcarla como la solución 

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso estoy trabajando con Python-Django 2.2 y mi codigo arrojaba el mismo mensaje de error en la consola:

> uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token

El error estaba dentro del template, tontamente habia realizado un comentario dentro del JS  como si fuere codigo html.

```
<script> 
<!--sólo debe llevar '/' al principio del STR la clave listar-->
var opcionesContexto = {listar:"/usuarios/listar_usuario/", editar:"usuarios/actualizar_usuario/",}
</script>
```

Cambiando el codigo anterior por el siguiente:

```
<script> 
// sólo debe llevar '/' al principio del STR la clave listar
var opcionesContexto = {listar:"/usuarios/listar_usuario/", editar:"usuarios/actualizar_usuario/",}
</script>
```

Y magicamente mis errores dejaron de salir por consola.

Otra recomendacion que podría hacer para los novatos como yo, es que prueben con diferentes navegadores, en mi caso firefox (mi navegador predeterminado) en el debugger de consola no me ayudaba a encontrar el problema, siempre me dirigia a la fila 1:3 del html, pero al probar con Edge o Chrome ante el mismo escenario/error, estos últimos me dirigían a partes del código próximas al error.

Salu2, y espero que le sirva a otro.

Comment: Esto no responde al problema planteado.